# Qpython3.6 - Using androidhelper module, getting unexpected results

Tags: android, qpython

Here is my current code:

```
>>>import androidhelper as andr

>>>d = andr.Android()

>>>dir(d) #returns all possible methods for the module

>>>d.batteryGetLevel() #Returns the following:
Result(id=1, result=None, error=None)
```

I don't understand why that is being printed instead of an integer between 1-100. How do I fix this to show my phone's current battery power? Can I use a similar feature to monitor Moto Mod battery?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. The problem here isn't the code its just that qpython doesn't have the permission to access the phones sensors through a script. If you really want to do this you may want to use kivy. Or make another app entirely.
Sorry I know this didn't help, but its the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the wrong command.
Try this script

```
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
battery =droid.readBatteryData().result
print(battery)
```

Comment: My result was None (instead of 44).